# How to make a virtual file in php

Tags: php, virtual-file

Let my site url be http://example.com .

Suppose if the user is entering the url http://example.com/profile_**103**.php , i need to display the profile of  user having an id **103** and the file profile_**103**.php does not exist. I need to get the values extracted  from the file name that the  user types .

How can i do this in php ?

Comment: Take a look @ [URL rewriting with PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16388959/url-rewriting-with-php)

Comment: Why do you have to do it like this? Isn't it better to use `/profile/103` then use uri rewriting to get the parameter?

Comment: All of these http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=htaccess+rewrite

Answer (score 0):

Quick & dirty solution with Apache & PHP for http://example.com/profile_103.php:

1. Make sure you have RewriteEngine on in Apache
2. Make an .htaccessfile with the following content:

   RewriteEngine on
   RedirectMatch 403 /..*$
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule . index.php
3. Content of index.php is:

   $userId = str_replace('.php', '', str_replace("/profile_", '', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']));
   echo $userId;